# How to resolve BufferError: Existing exports of data: object cannot be re-sized in tornado

Tags: python-2.7, tornado

I am a new user to Tornado web server.While streaming the data I got buffer error.Currently, I am using 4.5.1 version.Can anyone suggest the reason and resolve buffer error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is discussed in [Tornado issue 2008](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/pull/2008). The current theory is that it only happens when threads are being used incorrectly, but this is not certain. If you can rule out threading problems or provide more detail about how to reproduce it, please add comments to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error is resolved as part of latest release of tornado 4.5.3

For more details, look through the below link..

https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/1704

Answer (score 0):

Running Tornado 5.1 on embedded Linux. And I had same issues.

I was having a MQTT / Websocket bridge. Of course MQTT runs on one thread and Websocket (Tornado) on another. Most of the time everything was fine, but like every 1000th message crashed the program.

I cleverly had first direct class method to send data from MQTT thread. I got the following Exception:

"Existing exports of data: object cannot be re-sized"

I thought ok, I just had wrong ioloop. I changed:

```
websocket_thread = threading.Thread(target=tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start)
=>
websocket_thread = threading.Thread(target=tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start)
```

It worked better. But I started to get crashes with empty line as exception. I finally attached stack trace printing and see:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 587, in write
    self._handle_write()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 1063, in _handle_write
    self._write_buffer.advance(num_bytes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 184, in advance
    assert 0 < size <= self._size
AssertionError

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The empty line.
```

Then I realized from documents that Tornado was trying to send from 2 threads at exactly the same time, and it failed on size difference. **My solution was to replace the original function to one scheduling sent with ioloop add_callback function**:

```
# Called from other thread => need to use add callback                                                                                                         
# to schedule send from owner thread                                                                                                                           
@classmethod
def send_message(cls, msg_str):
    cls.ioloop.add_callback(cls.send_message_to_all, msg_str)
```

This seems to finally have solved my issues.